# PHP-FPM Cannot Get UID For User

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I have setup an AWS EC2 linux instance and installed the following:

```
httpd24 php71 php71-fpm php71-mysqlnd mod24_ssl fcgi mod24_fcgid
```

I am wanting to run apache 2.4, php 7.1 and php-fpm. In the below error I am also not understanding what 'nginx' is trying to do, I didn't think I had installed anything to run on nginx, if I am running apache.

```
ERROR: [pool www] cannot get uid for user 'nginx': Success (0)
```

In php-fpm.conf, uncommented I have this

```
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-7.1.pid
```

In my php-fpm.conf I do not see

```
user = apache
group = apache
```

But I do see them in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

Can somebody please help me sort this out.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Resolved found in the /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf, I found this line.

```
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

Solution - change to

```
listen.acl_users = apache
```

Comment: I had the same issue but in reverse; I have nginx and making it `= nginx` like your answer fixed it. You encounter this issue if you use groupdel on apache or nginx postinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by adding user `www-data` and adding `www-data` to group `www-data`

```
sudo adduser www-data
sudo usermod -a -G www-data www-data
sudo systemctl restart php-fpm
```